# Cmake cannot add "-fPIE" flag to makefile

Tags: python, c++, linux, cmake, g++

I'm trying to compile C++ code with python embedded in it. The compiler does not compile my code with '-fPIE' flag even though I've added it in  CMakeList.txt. Here's my CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(TestCython)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.8-6QL2k7/python3.8-3.8.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIE")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.8-6QL2k7/python3.8-3.8.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIE")

# Eigen
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

# Embedded Python Includes
include_directories(/usr/include/python3.8
                    /usr/include/eigen3/    )

# Embedded Python Linker
link_directories(/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
                 /usr/lib)

target_link_libraries(  main
            python3.8
            crypt
            pthread
            dl
            util
            m   )       

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
```

If I run the generated make file, it will report a lot of similar errors and ask me to recompile with '-fPIE', like this one:
**/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a(call.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE**

The compilation succeeds if I don't use cmake:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/python3.8  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.8-6QL2k7/python3.8-3.8.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIE main.cpp -o main -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

Cmake version is 3.16.3. Python version is 3.8.2. System is Ubuntu 20.04
How can I solve those errors?

Comment: Why do you set all these variables? That's not the recommended way, e.g. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_compile_features.html Why do you set the compiler in CMake?

Comment: Manually setting the flags in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not recommended, but if you really must do it this way, you should set them prior to calling `add_executable()`. You should really set these flags in [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that most of the time this error has nothing to do with the `PIE` flag but is rather something else screwy about your build, unfortunately it’s a bit hard to tell because your CMake config is a bit screwy.

This particular error however is probably because you’re setting your properties incorrectly; Setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and similar variables does nothing if you do it *after* defining your target with `add_executable`. This can be avoided entirely by using a more modern CMake style (out of scope for this answer, just google *Modern CMake* for some examples), in this particular case instead of setting flags on those variables you could for example do

```
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE -fpie)
```

Comment: I've replaced all the **set cmake_c_flags** with **target_compile_options** and it still reports the same error. I doubt if gcc really compiles my code with **-fPIE**. Those flags are output of `python3-config --cflags --embed`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when I linked my library `env2048` (having a file called `ppo_buffer`) to my bindings module `env2048bindings`:

```
[build] FAILED: python/env2048bindings.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
[build] : && /usr/bin/g++-7 -fPIC -g   -shared  -o python/env2048bindings.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so python/CMakeFiles/env2048bindings.dir/env2048/bindings.cpp.o  src/libenv2048.a  -pthread && :
[build] /usr/bin/ld: src/libenv2048.a(ppo_buffer.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZSt3minIlERKT_S2_S2_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
[build] /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I had to set the properties for the *library* to make it work with:

```
set_target_properties(env2048 PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

From these, I would make the guess that you might need this:

```
set_target_properties(python3.8 PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```